# extracting most recent row contatining longitude and latitude added into table in database

Tags: android, mysql

We have created an android app where multiple users of this app sends its coordinates on server in a table named 'data' after a regular intervals of time. which has 3 columns "bus_id", "longitude", "latitude".Each user has a particular id. The table structure is:

```
data
bus_id    longitude    latitude
--------------------------------
```

Along with coordinates they also send their id to server. There is no primary key in that table. Now we want to extract the most recent entry for a particular user. so is there a way to do so or we have to define a primary key??
or is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract a 'most recent' entry (by specific user or otherwise), you need some way of keeping track of the individual records, either by an autoincrement ID or by a date field.

With just the three columns that you show, there's no basis on which to do a query for 'most recent' - you can only search, sort and filter by the attributes present in the table.

Using an autoincrement ID field:

```
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE bus_id = 'specific_user' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

will select records for a specific user (specified by bus_id), order them in descending order by the autoincrement ID, and return the top record, which will be the record with the highest ID number and hence the most recent record (for that user).

Comment: if we add auto increment id then how can we access the last updated record for a particular user?